# Twilio call forwarding from caller to third party number

Tags: twilio, call, forwarding

I want to ask if it's possible to forward call not from called side but from caller? For example, first user calls to second user. Second user picks up. Then system (or second user) automatically (or on button click somewhere)  calls to third user and the first user hangs up the call so when third user picks up then there are second user and third user on the call?
Thanks.

I was able to forward call from called user to thid party but the common user was caller. For example it's described here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-nodejs-express but it's not what I need. I want to forward call from caller not from called user.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This seems like something you could achieve using a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference). You could have the first user dial a Twilio number that dropped them into a conference call with the following TwiML

```
<Response>
  <Dial hangupOnStar="true" action="/dial-next-user">
    <Conference>Forwarder</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

This would set the initial caller to listen to hold music. You could then initiate an outbound call with the REST API to caller 2 by [creating a participant for the conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only). This will dial the user into the conference too.

Now, to get caller 1 to hangup and connect to caller 3. Notice I included [`hangupOnStar="true"` to the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar). This would allow caller 1 to press `*` and leave the call. When they do that Twilio will make a webhook to the URL defined by the `action` attribute. You can then respond to that request by [dialling in caller 3 using the same participants API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only) and thus achieving connecting caller 1 to 2 and then 2 to 3.

Let me know if that helps at all.